# Is it possible to remove blocks on local environement?

Tags: blocks, magento2.2, local

As I have seen in other topics that some things were not working on local environment I was asking myself if it shoukd be the same problem with removing blocks. I have folowed Magento instructions and have looked for same issues but didn't found anything.

In fact I have tried to remove the catalog.compare.sidebar block from

> MAMP/htdocs/mysite/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

by adding a **default.xml** file into

> MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/design/frontend/bertrand/luma_child/Magento_catalog/layout

with

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true" />
  </body>
</page>
```

I have cleared all the caches but,
unfortunately, this doesn't work at all. What is strange is that if I override a phtml file using the same method, there is no problem.

I have also tried with other xml files and it is always the same issue. I should make a mistake or forgot something, but I really don't find and after a full day of investigation I'm lost.

If somebody can help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try to change name of the folder `Magento_catalog` to `Magento_Catalog`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your answer but I have already tried but same issue. And as it works fine with the phtml files...